# pyvmomi create resource pool

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere

When I use pyVmomi to create a resource pool, I am getting an `Invalid parameter` error. My code is as follows:

```
from pyVim import connect
import atexit
import logging
from pyVmomi import vim
import datetime
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3                                                                                                                                                          
from keystoneauth1 import session
from novaclient import client
from pyVim import connect
import atexit
import logging
from pyVmomi import vim
import datetime

auth = v3.Password(auth_url="http://192.168.3.201:5000/v3", username="admin",password="admin",
                project_name="admin",user_domain_id="default", project_domain_id="default")
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
nova = client.Client('2.1',session=sess)
si = connect.SmartConnect(host='192.168.3.13', user='administrator@vsphere.local', pwd='!QAZ2wsx')
atexit.register(connect.Disconnect, si)
dc = si.content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
cr = dc.hostFolder.childEntity[0]

import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
rootResourcePool = cr.resourcePool
#rootResourcePool = vim.ResourcePool('cxl')
rp_spec = vim.ResourceConfigSpec()

alla = vim.ResourceAllocationInfo()
alla.limit = -1
alla.expandableReservation = True
alla.reservation = 12
rp_spec.cpuAllocation = alla

blla = vim.ResourceAllocationInfo()
blla.limit = -1
blla.expandableReservation = True
blla.reservation = 12
rp_spec.memoryAllocation = blla

rp_obj = rootResourcePool.CreateResourcePool('123', rp_spec)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
(Pdb) rootResourcePool.CreateResourcePool('123', rp_spec)
*** vmodl.fault.InvalidArgument: (vmodl.fault.InvalidArgument) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
   msg = u'\u6307\u5b9a\u7684\u53c2\u6570\u4e0d\u6b63\u786e: ',
   faultCause = <unset>,
   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) [],
   invalidProperty = <unset>
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error?

I have tried this with github, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

We have to specify all the attributes of the `alla = vim.ResourceAllocationInfo()` object except the **overheadLimit**.

Add:

```
alla.shares (vim.SharesInfo):
blla.shares (vim.SharesInfo):
```

[Doc for vim.ResourceAllocation Attribute](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/ResourceAllocationInfo.rst)