# How to Specify a Location for Creating a VMware Resource Pool with PyVmomi?

Tags: python-3.x, vxworks, pyvmomi

I'm trying to create a VMware pool at a specific point in the tree using PyVmomi. It looks like I don't have permission to create the pool in the root folder, so how can I set a particular point? I'm using an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968119/pyvmomi-create-resource-pool) to create a resource pool with PyVmomi, but it's without comments, and I'm just debugging the reply structure to understand how to fill it in the right way.

Would appreciate any thoughts or advice